# Facebook SDK permissions on different events

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app I need user to log in using either Facebook or email. Then they can select images from Facebook or from Local storage.

When I login in the app using Facebook I doing it like this

```
     FB.login(function (response) {
      },
    {scope: 'email'});
```

I know in the scope I can ask permission for the user photos as well but I have seen then most of the user don't get in to my app seeing that they have to give permissions for a lot of stuff.

In my api call for albums from Facebook I am doing like this

```
FB.api('/me/albums', function (resp) {
},{scope:'user_photos'});
```

But I get the 'resp' as empty array.

Is there a better way to do that? Like get permissions on different events in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB.api does not use the scope parameter, but you can call FB.login again to request additional permissions:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me/albums', ...
    }
}, {scope: 'user_photos'});
```

You may want to check what permissions already are accepted right when you start the App though, and only call FB.login if you know the User did not authorize your App or did not accept a specific permission yet:

```
FB.api(
    "/me/permissions",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/permissions